# Sending an email from a bash script on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: bash, macos, email

I have the local smtp relay setup correctly, I have several scripts using a simple one line-ish mail command:

```
echo "I am the body." | mail -s "I am the subject." notamango.me@company.com -F "ReplyToPrettyName" -f ReplyToAdrress@server.com
```

This was working on 10.9.5, it has broken after an update to 10.10.5. Ok, I get that they changed something, but now I can't seem to get it to work. Has anyone successfully sent emails from a bash script in mac osx 10.10.5+ using a one line-ish command where I can specify the sender and replyto address? I am about to write a small piece to do the raw telnet commands if I have to, as installing non default apps isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Took me some futzing about but this seems to be working:

```
echo "I am the body" | mail -s "$(echo -e "I am the subject.\nFrom: PrettyName <PrettyName@Server.com>\n REALReplytoAddress@Server.com\nContent-Type: text/html\n")" 'recipient.me@company.com'
```

Hope this helps someone else who is stuck.